# Javascript regex - split string by string between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Say i have a string like so

> Shoes {cakes} marry me {fiona:banana|cheese} and then {i want}

I want to get an array like so

> ["Shoes", " marry me ", " and then "]

or even

> ["Shoes", " marry me ", " and then ", ""]

I know that if i have a single char, e.g.

> Shoes {a} marry me {b} and then {c}

I can do 
`"Shoes {a} marry me {b} and then {c}".split(/\{.\}/)` to get my result.

I tried

```
"Shoes {cakes} marry me {fiona:banana|cheese} and then {i want}".split(/\{(.*)\}/)
```

But my result looks like

> ["Shoes ", "cakes} marry me {fiona:banana|cheese} and then {i want", ""]

Comment: `.split(/{.*?}/)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` will take as much as it can ("greedy repetition"). `.*?` will take as little as possible:

```js
let haystack = "Shoes {cakes} marry me {fiona:banana|cheese} and then {i want}";
let needle = /{.*?}/;
console.log(haystack.split(needle));
// => ["Shoes ", " marry me ", " and then ", ""]
```